# Accessing Qt GUI ui from another class OR using connect() to update gui elements

Tags: c++, qt

I need some help understanding how to access the QT GUI ui from another class/another cpp file.

**Background:**  I am working on a project that consists of many cpp and hpp files. I am not the original author. This project is to control a USRP to receive/send data....with various parameters. Originally, you had to manually change parameter values inside several cpp files (i..e start frequency, steps, duration of receive, etc). Then re-compile and then run the executable. I wrote a simple Qt GUI interface in the main.cpp function where the users would enter in the GUI basic usrp receive parameters. Then the GUI interface would pass these values back into the uspr function that would actually execute the USRP functionality. This part is actually working great and I am happy (my first GUI!, Yay!)

One thing that I would like to do is to also display the current frequency in the main GUI window via the LCDNumber widget. This frequency is managed by another class, in another cpp file.

Here is what I tried:

**Attempt #1:**  Make the MainWindow ui publicly available int the class/cpp file where the Frequency is established:

```
freq_transmit.cpp:
......
#include "mainwindow.hpp"
#include "ui_mainwindow.hpp"
.....
void Receiver::run()
{
   //bunch of lines of code about USRP stuff
    .....
   rxCenterFreq // <---variable that holds the current frequency (which changes every second)
   ui->lcdnumber->display(rxCenterFreq);  // <-- -compiler error:  ui not declared in this scope
  ............
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QPalette>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPalette temp_red;
    QPalette temp_green;

private slots:
    void on_button_CalcSchedule_clicked();
    void on_button_Reset_clicked();
    void execute_run_usrp();    
    void on_button_QUIT_clicked();    
    void on_AutoSchedulerCheckBox_stateChanged(int arg1);    
    void on_button_manul_CalcSchedule_clicked();    
    void on_button_EXECUTE_clicked();    
    void on_button_SeeSchedule_clicked();
    void on_button_STOP_clicked();    
    void function_test();

public slots:
    void updateTXFreq(double a);

private:    
    void reset_sweep_values();
    std::string calc_schedule_start_time(int minute_cadence);
    void calc_cadence();
    double calc_sweep_duration();
    int nearest_cadence(int numToRound, int multiple);

signals:
    void send_start_schedule(std::string, double, int, int);
    
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

**Attempt #2:  Use Qt CONNECT functionality:**

**Step 1:  generate a SIGNAL / emit function in the freq_transmit.hpp header:**

```
....

signals:
     void sendTXFreq(double a);
```

**Step 2:  Enter this emit signal in the freq_transmit.cpp file where the Frequency is being generated:**

```
freq_transmit.cpp:
    ......
    #include "mainwindow.hpp"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.hpp"
    .....
    void Receiver::run()
    {
       //bunch of lines of code about USRP stuff
        .....
       emit sendTXFreq(rxCenterFreq); // emit signal to QT
       ....
```

**Step 3:  Declare a SLOT in mainwindow.h to accept emitted signal**

mainwindow.hpp:

```
...
public slots:
    void updateTXFreq(double a);
```

**Step 4:  Implementation:**

mainwindow.cpp:

```
....

void MainWindow::updateTXFreq(double a)
{
     ui->lcdnumber->display(a);
}

connect(&Receiver, &Receiver::sendTXFreq, this, &MainWindow::updateTXFreq); // <-- error: expected primary expression before ','
```

which is the comma after "&Receiver", which is a class that has various functions in it, including the Receiver::run() where Frequency is generated.`

Long story short, I am trying to have the generated frequency linked to a LCDNumber widget so that it shows on the GUI the value of frequency as the USRP code runs.

PS:  I am not an expert C++ coder, I am just now learning about classes and QT GUI. Somebody mentioned that I should "create a pointer of my MainWindow in the freq_transmit.cpp file" so that then I can accesss ui elements direclty in that class, but I thought I tried that with ui->lcdnumber->display(rxCenterFreq);

Any guidance much appreciated and thank you!

Comment: `ui->lcdnumber->display(rxCenterFreq);` Don't try to access a `ui` directly from a different class. Instead use signals and slots with a slot in your widget class.

Comment: Signal/slot pair, possibly with queued connection type if multithreading is involved, seems better. Difficult to say more based on the description and snippets you have shown.